# How to configure SSH password-free login from Mac OS to Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, mac

I tried executing the following command on Mac OS:

```bash
ssh-copy-id windows_username@windows_ip
```

however, the following results were returned, and password-free login was not configured successfully:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/Users/mac_username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
windows_username@windows_ip's password:
'exec' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
�������ļ���

Number of key(s) added:        1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'windows_username@windows_ip'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

Why does garbled code appear? I opened the `authorized_keys` file on the windows system myself, the content of which are as follows(The systems I use are all in Chinese):

```
ECHO 处于打开状态。
```

This content translated into English is: `ECHO is on`. Why does this happen?

Later, I manually copied the public key on the Mac OS to the `authorized_keys` file in Windows, but I still couldn't log in to Windows on the Mac OS without a password.

How to deal with this? I've tried everything I can think of. Thank you in advance for your help.

---

**Update:**
According to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1407020/logging-into-windows-10-openssh-server-with-administrator-account-and-public-key), it mentions commenting out the following two lines in the `sshd_config` file:

```
Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

When I commented out these two lines and manually added the public key on the Mac OS to `authorized_keys`, the password-free login did take effect.

But adding it manually seems a bit clumsy. Then I deleted file `authorized_keys`, and then tried to use `ssh-copy-id` to automatically add it. The result was that it was not added successfully. Why?

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1407020/logging-into-windows-10-openssh-server-with-administrator-account-and-public-key) help with the problem?

Comment: @harrymc It did solve my problem to some extent, but I still haven't figured out a few things, so please see my update.